# Linearized exponential regression by lm() vs. non-linear nls() regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

### Disclaimer

I am new to this site, relatively new to R (two weeks of learning), have just a really basic knowledge in statistics so sorry if I'm doing a dumb mistake there or asking bad question or something.

I also don't know how to nicely embed my dataset into post (I searched meta without finding anything about this) so I shared a link from Google Drive (if you know a better way, please let me know and I can change it or do it yourself if you have the right to edit).

### Explanation

In physical Laboratory course I am attending I have done an experiment to determine attenuation coefficient of an optical medium using optical filters of different thicknesses (with this spectrometer http://www.vernier.com/products/sensors/spectrometers/visible-range/v-spec/).

It generated data which you can download here to reproduce my results: https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B5x0REqWCRBuaHlXc2JWZ19sWE0&export=download

My goal is to determine $\kappa(\lambda)$, where $\kappa$ is the attenuation coefficient and $\lambda$ wavelenght, using Beer–Lambert law which states ($l$ is the thickness): 
$$\theta=x_0 \cdot \exp(-\kappa \cdot l)$$

I have 5 "curves" for different thicknesses of optical filters (from 1 to 5 mm) and I fit the exponential model for each wavelenght $\lambda$ which gives me the $\kappa$ for that wavelenght.

I tried this:

**Linearized model**

by taking logarithm of the equation above and some algebraic manipulation we get: $$ \ln \left( \frac{x_0}{\theta} \right) = \kappa \cdot l$$

represented by R command `lm( I(log(x0/temp.theta)) ~ l + 0 )`

**Non-linear model**

I take the Beer–Lambert law (first equation) and model it by `nls(temp.theta ~ I(x0 * exp(-k*l)) + 0 , start= list(k = k.l))`, where is obtained from the linearized model `k.l = coef(lm(...))`.

### Code for reproduction

I set `x0 = 100` since $\theta$ is measured in percents.

```
x0 = 100 #x=0 intercept of the exp function

data = read.delim2("export2.csv")

l = data$l
l = l[-which(is.na(l))]
data$l = NULL

data$kappa.l = NA
data$sd.l = NA
data$kappa.nl = NA
data$sd.nl = NA

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){

  temp.theta = as.numeric(data[i,-which(names(data) %in% c("lambda","kappa.l","kappa.nl","sd.l","sd.nl"))])
  temp.lm = lm( I(log(x0/temp.theta)) ~ l + 0 )
  k.l = coef(temp.lm)
  data[i , "kappa.l"] = k.l
  data[i , "sd.l"] = coef(summary(temp.lm))[ ,"Std. Error"]

  temp.nls = nls(temp.theta ~ I(x0 * exp(-k*l)) + 0,  start = list(k = k.l))
  data[i , "kappa.nl"] = coef(temp.nls)
  data[i , "sd.nl"] = coef(summary(temp.nls))[ ,"Std. Error"]

}
```

### Questions

When I visualize the result I get the graph below. These questions emerge:

- Why are the fits so much different around the 400 nm wavelenght?
- Which one fits the data better?
- Or are the data so far from exponential behavior there so I have to cut them where they meet?
- Which of these models is statistically (more) correct?
- Can I make the fits better by adding weights according to the measurement uncertainty (which I believe to be 5 % as stated on the Vernier web)?

**the fit with higher values is the non-linear one**
[image: kappa(lambda)]

Comment: Your two fits don't tell me much without data to compare them to.

Comment: @Glen_b: I've plotted the data and now I see why all attempts to fit it are foolish. I will post it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the disclaimer it was a dumb mistake. If I would have plotted the actual data it would become obvious why the models don't fit (as any other exponential model of that kind wouldn't).

It's probably issue of the spectrometer because it's probably not sensible enough to capture that low trasmittance hence there are practcally zeros for all five measurements so fitting an exponential curve to that makes no sense.

I am sorry for wasting your time guys.

[image: data visualization]
[image: detail]